# Separate lines in facet_grid labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is there a way to print the text shown in the facet_grid label on separate lines? In the example below I would like to "Test" to be printed above "Group". I have been trying using ggtext, but I don't get it to work. Does anyone know of some way to do it?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

df <- tibble(X = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","B","B","B","C","C"),
             value = c(5,2,7,3,1,6,9,4,2,5,2),
             type = c("t","t","t","t","t","s","s","s","s","s", "s"),
             group = c("T1G1","T2G2","T1G1","T2G2","T1G1","T1G1","T3G3","T2G2","T3G3","T3G3", "T3G3"))

re_names <- c(
  "T1G1" = "Test1<b>Group1",
  "T2G2" = "Test2<b>Group2",
  "T3G3" = "Test3<b>Group3")

df %>% ggplot(aes(X,value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=type)) +
  facet_grid(~group,
             labeller = as_labeller(re_names))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `<b>`.

Comment: Thanks! That was easily done. 
How do I close the post if my question is answered as a comment?

Comment: If @caldwellst isn't interested in posting his comment as an answer, you can post your own answer, giving credit to caldwellst and accept your own answer. If later caldwellst decide to post an answer, you can always accept that answer instead of your own so that he gets the points for his answer.

Comment: another option is to answer as a wiki, if you're not happy with the idea of getting the points for someone else's answer. But I can see that the answer has been posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `\n` instead of `<b>`.

```r
re_names <- c(
  "T1G1" = "Test1\nGroup1",
  "T2G2" = "Test2\nGroup2",
  "T3G3" = "Test3\nGroup3")

df %>% ggplot(aes(X,value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=type)) +
  facet_grid(~group,
             labeller = as_labeller(re_names))
```

[image]